# Haskell - adding a package from source to a Yesod project

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod, haskell-stack

I have found a good audio library to deal with audio on server side, but I am having trouble while actually making it part of yesod (maybe because I don't understand cabal/stack very well yet).

I am trying to include this module `Sound.File.Sndfile` and I have downloaded its source files from here http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.27.tar.gz. Which are the steps to get it done?

**Edit**

I tried to make this steps

```
runhaskell Setup.hs configure --ghc
runhaskell Setup.hs build
runhaskell Setup.hs install
```

But it doesn't have a `Setup.hs` file.

**EDIT 2**

I have added the dependency `hsndfile` as suggested by Alexis King, but I am getting the following error while buiding:

```
[ 1 of 59] Compiling Enums            ( Enums.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.7.0/build/Enums.o )
<command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: libsndfile.so (libsndfile.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

--  While building package Fastwork-0.0.0 using:
      /home/geppetto/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.7.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.7.0 build lib:Fastwork exe:Fastwork --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I have downloaded `libsndfile-1.0.25.tar.gz` and I extracted it, and ran, ./configure, make, make install. When I tried to do a `stack build` again in my Yesod project, the error was the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason that you can’t use [any of these libraries that are already on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=libsndfile)? It will probably be much easier, safer, and more predictable if you’re using a package from an actual package catalog rather that just using a tarball.

If you *really* want to use that library you found, and you’re using stack, you can add it to the `packages` section of your `stack.yaml` file:

```
packages:
- '.'
- location: http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.27.tar.gz
  extra-dep: true
```

Then you can add a dependency on `libsndfile` to your `.cabal` file. However, I would be wary on depending on packages from arbitrary URLs, so I would probably, at the very least, download that package and untar it. Then you can just point to a local path instead of a remote URL:

```
packages:
- '.'
- location: ./some/path/to/libsndfile
  extra-dep: true
```

For more information, see the [documentation for the `stack.yaml` file](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/).

Comment: I will try this other way, there is no need for it to be from source